# Lua - querying with a variable in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, lua

In my app I use the scene transitions. I get one value from scene1 and pass it to scene2 using

```
local routeId = storyboard.state.routeId
```

This works fine. Next I'd like to get all the data, using routeId. For this I use:

```
for row in db:nrows("SELECT * FROM route WHERE route_id = routeId") do
...
```

This doesn't work. I have been looking at parametrized queries, binding values, SQL injection, etc. But since I'm a beginner this is all pretty advanced stuff for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Prepared Statements with Parameters (Binding)](http://www.nessie.de/mroth/lua-sqlite3/documentation.html#ref11)

```
stmt = db:prepare("SELECT * FROM route WHERE route_id = ?")
stmt:bind(routeId)
stmt:exec()
```

Comment: I have put your code into mine, and it says "attempt to call a method 'exec' (a nil value). What have I missed? How can I get then the data out of SQLite? Before I have used for row in db:nrows...

Comment: @jumbee, that's because it is SELECT statement, so you should use `:first_cols` or `:cols`. Otherwise the main point of answer is 100% correct: always use prepared statements.

Comment: This was the solution I was looking for:                            for row in db:nrows("SELECT * FROM route WHERE route_id = " .. routeId) do                                                              Thank you for all your help...